# How do I count number of classes and methods in java project by passing the path of that project?

Tags: java

I am developing a java project in which I will pass the path of another java project file and it will display the total number of classes, methods, variables and their type in that particular project. I will pass the path with the help of file handling but what kind of code should I write to display the number of classes and methods?

Comment: to get the number of variables and methods you can use the Reflect api (look around x.class.getMethods()/getFields() )  but to get all the classes in a project isnt gonna be easy (in eclipse plugin development you can get a dependency for that oO ) you mgiht be able to do some roundabout way by doing a console command to get the paths for all classes and then loading them into a classloader

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to install and invoke an external tool from your program that supports this for Java language. One example of such tool would be [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc):

> cloc counts blank lines, comment lines, and physical lines of source code in many programming languages.